# How to convert this date format

Tags: time, timestamp

I have wierd date format:

```
ID, Time,  Value 1 [mg/l]
9867, 43788.5946644, 5.266029
9851, 43788.5529745, 5.526279
9835, 43788.5113079, 6.008881
```

and I would like to convert it, but I can not even recognize this one. an anyone help me? It might be conversion to timestamp, simple date or anything else that is readable.

I know the outputs:

```
43788.5946644 - 19/11/2019 14:16
43788.5529745 - 19/11/2019 13:16
43788.5113079 - 19/11/2019 12:16
```

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: I don't know ;/

oh I should have said that I know the outputs for these tree, but don't know how o convert anything else.
`43788.5946644 - 19/11/2019 14:16 ;
43788.5529745 - 19/11/2019 13:16 ;
43788.5113079 - 19/11/2019 12:16`

Comment: Thank you @richyen for good question, you helped me find an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

By accident I found an answer, this is a excell date. https://www.excel-exercise.com/date-format-in-excel/

can be converted using powershell command:

```
 [DateTime]::FromOADate(43788.5946528) -> Tuesday, November 19 2019 14:16:18
```